# Is there any way to make print a web with window.print from a input?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this code but it didn't work.

The button didn't respond.

My code is

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input style= "top:80%; left:5%; width:40%;" type="text" id="userInput" />
    <script>
        document.getElementById("userInput").value
</script>
<button onclick="window.print(userInput)">Print The Page</button>
```

Comment: Works for me. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Firefox v104

Comment: Works for me. Windows 10 /  Chrome

Comment: Works for me as well (Chrome on Win 10), however there are some flaws in your code: The code inside the `<script>` tags doesn't do anything, since you do not assign the value of the input to a variable. Also `window.print` does not take any arguments, so passing `userInput` to it is pointless (`userInput` is `undefined` anyway)

Comment: Dude If You are Running on Firefox It can Show Some Error Try Running on Microsoft Edge or Chrome

Comment: I'm running it on a mobile app called QuickEdit

Comment: @Marc If You Search It Firefox Always Show Error While Printing The Page and its a common issue so I thought it ill be helpful.

Comment: @NoobPlayZ - You do know that right-click Print works on most browsers.